# How can I visualize and process this 3d data

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have a 3 dimensional data look like this

```
   x1,x2,x3,x4
y1 0  0  0  3
y2 3  2  0  4 
y3 1  4  0  0 
...
```

I would like to visualize this in 3d map
so I think I need to reshape the data in this form

```
x  y  z
-------
x1 y1 0
x1 y2 3
x1 y3 1
x2 y1 0
x2 y2 0
x2 y3 0 
x3 y1 3
x3 y3 4
```

my actual data have ca 900 x observations and 7000 y observations so if there is other way to visualize this data without reshaping, it would be also helpful

Comment: I think reshaping is the only way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a matrix into column array with PANDAS / Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474284/how-to-convert-a-matrix-into-column-array-with-pandas-python)

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to do in R. Suppose I have a matrix like this:

```r
set.seed(69)
m <- matrix(rpois(100, 5), nrow = 10, dimnames = list(y = 1:10, x = 1:10))
m
#>     x
#> y    1 2 3 4  5 6 7  8  9 10
#>   1  5 8 4 6 11 5 5  5  6  6
#>   2  7 4 3 8  4 7 2  6  5  7
#>   3  6 8 6 4  5 6 1  8  5  5
#>   4  7 3 4 5  6 4 5  7  6  4
#>   5  4 3 3 4  3 9 1  2 10  2
#>   6  8 3 3 6  1 6 8 10  5  3
#>   7  3 2 6 6  2 3 4  4  6  5
#>   8  7 6 6 5  3 3 5  5  7  3
#>   9  3 2 2 4  4 7 8  4  5  4
#>   10 1 7 4 5  3 6 6  6  6  5
```

I can reshape it into x, y and value columns like this:

```
library(reshape2)

df <- melt(m)
```

And plot it like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c() + coord_equal() + theme_minimal()
```

[image]

You don't have to worry about computation time for reshaping either. Here's the benchmark for reshaping a 700 * 900 matrix:

```
 m <- matrix(rpois(630000, 5), nrow = 700, dimnames = list(y = 1:700, x = 1:900))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(melt(m))
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>     expr     min       lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
#>  melt(m) 10.5401 13.45535 16.60985 14.1058 14.8661 79.3941   100
```

It only takes 14 milliseconds, so your big matrix can be reshaped about 7 times in [the blink of an eye.](https://sciencing.com/fast-blink-eye-5199669.html)

Comment: thanks, I want to try this but got Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'x' not found. I have an excel data.What option should i add when I do df <- melt(m?)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option

```
cbind(`colnames<-`(rev(expand.grid(attributes(m)$dimnames)),c("x","y")),z = c(m))
```

which gives

```
    x  y  z
1  x1 y1  1
2  x1 y2  2
3  x1 y3  3
4  x2 y1  4
5  x2 y2  5
6  x2 y3  6
7  x3 y1  7
8  x3 y2  8
9  x3 y3  9
10 x4 y1 10
11 x4 y2 11
12 x4 y3 12
```

**Data**

```
> dput(m)
structure(1:12, .Dim = 3:4, .Dimnames = list(c("y1", "y2", "y3"
), c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4")))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would be satisfied with heatmap visualization, there are two options to implement this:

1. Pandas [styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Builtin-styles):

```py
    df.style.background_gradient(cmap='viridis')
```

[image: styling example]

2. Seaborn [heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

```py
    import seaborn as sns
    sns.heatmap(df, annot=True)
```

[image: seaborn example]